# bash: ufw: command not found after installing ufw on Google Cloud console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I'm working on Google Cloud console. I need to enable firewall. I need to access some ports. I've installed ufw via apt-get install ufw but, still I see bash: ufw: command not found. Could you help me?

[Here is the screen where the problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JALxM.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Your question lacks almost all detail. What did you do to install ufw? What happened when you tried `ufw --help`? It is relevant to ask why you need ufw? Compute Engine includes a firewall "service" that can (!) be used instead of instance-specific firewalls such as ufw. You may (!?) be able to use Compute Engine's (VPC) [Firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1) You do not need the UFW firewall on Google Cloud. Use the Google Cloud VPC Firewall. 2) UFW is installed but is not part of your shell's PATH.

Comment: Thanks @John Hanley !